# Create a new date

Tags: datetime

Ok why isnt this working?  it keeps saying Variable does not exist DateTime on the second to last line?

```
String svalue = '2014-06-06T04:00:00.000+0000';

DateTime tempDate;

try {
    tempDate = DateTime.valueOf(svalue);

} catch (TypeException e) {
    String year = svalue.substring(0,4);
    String month = svalue.substring(5,2);
    String day = svalue.substring(7,2);
    String hour = svalue.substring(10,2);
    String minute = svalue.substring(13,2);
    tempDate =  DateTime.newInstance(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This looks like poor error reporting by the compiler; the signature required is:

```
DateTime.newInstance(Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer)
```

so your local variables need to change to e.g.:

```
Integer year = Integer.valueOf(svalue.substring(0,4));
```

to eliminate that error.